# join two tables in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

I have two table ,

**Student** has the following columns

```
student_id
student_name
student_lastname
student_email
student_class
```

**Apsent**:

```
course_id
teacher_id
class_id
interval_id
day_id
student_id
state
```

So I want to join this two table to be in one table having following columns :

```
course_id
teacher_id
class_id
student_id
student_name ((( from student Table ! )))
```

Because I want to get all student information referenced by `student_id` from `Apsent` table .

I have tried something but i'm confusedg

I use mysql database .

Comment: This should be a simple join operation. what's the problem with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple and straightforward [`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) will give you what you want:

```
SELECT
  a.course_id,
  a.teach_id,
  a.class_id,
  s.student_id,
  s.student_name
FROM Student AS s
INNER JOIN Apsent AS a ON s.student_id = a.student_id;
```

You might need to use `LEFT JOIN` instead to include the unmatched rows, those students that has no ids in the other table.

Answer (score 0):

select A.course_id, A.teacher_id, A.class_id, A.student_id, S.student_name 
from Students as S join Apsent as A on S.student_id=A.student_id;